# Timeout when executing MERGE-statement in SQL Server 2016 in simple recovery model

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, sql-merge

After migrating from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2016, we have been experiencing query timeouts using MERGE-statements on some datasets.

Tested versions:
WORKING: SQL Server 2014 Enterprise (64-bit) (12.0.5532.0)
TIMEOUTS: SQL Server 2016 Enterprise (64-bit) (13.0.4001.0) and SQL Server 2016 Enterprise (64-bit) (13.0.1601.5)

Code to reproduce the timeout error: [enter link description here](http://pastebin.com/DXZJzyJv)

Comment: where are you executing it from (SSMS, osql, code, ...)? do execution plans differ?

Comment: What happen if you put the OUTPUT of the MERGE statements into a temporary table, then INSERT data from that temp table to the `TargetTable` later?

Comment: your EXCEPT command can generate demand on TempDB, is the provisioning of TempDB equal on both instances?